# Linear Regression vs Time Series

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression

beginner to stats. So I have an open ended analysis regarding the happiness of certain countries. I am given the following data:

1) Country
2) Happiness Score (Dependent Variable)
3) GDP per Capita
4) Life Expectancy
5) 9 dummy variables indicating the region

I have this data for 2015, 2016, 2017 and am trying to uncover some trends about how the independent variables affect happiness. I was going to do a basic multiple linear regression for each year to provide insight, but is there some way to tie these trends together over time? Or am I stuck with viewing this effect in "snapshots" for each year. Wondering if incorporating a time series somehow might be too difficult (again a beginner). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For starters please look at this https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are a complete beginner as you state, run the multiple linear regression with the happiness score (if it is indeed a continuous and not a categorical variable) for each country and look at the coefficients and whether or how they change.

This answers the question "how was country x1's happiness score in 2015, 2016 and 2017, controlled for GDP and life expectancy".

The issue with running several models is you accumulate more calculations for significance which means you run into a multiple comparison problem (potentially), but for a beginner I doubt any professor would criticize that.